# Excel. Changing Interior Color to match a cell with same value

Tags: excel, vba, colors

Morning all. Just a quick one for you!

I have two tables of times, and I'm looking to get the bottom tables interior colors to match the top tables. I'm wanting to do this in VBA as both table ranges are dynamic with a data refresh, I currently have a ForEach loop on the lower table with a named range (cpttimes), and the top tables times are in a named range too (times) if i can squeeze in some code in to set the interior.color at the same time that would be great! Had a look online already, but struggling to find some tidy code :)[image]

Tried a couple of methods so far but falling up short :)

Any ideas??

Comment: Please, share the code you tried, even if it does not do what you need. In this way we will maybe better understand what you try doing... Do you want `13:30` from the down table to have a blue interior, the following one according to the above one and so on? If not, what to be colored, according to what, please?

Comment: Are the two tables in discussion in the same sheet?

Comment: Yes both tables are on the same sheet. I haven't got any of the code that i was originally working on, i have tried a vba loop for each cell to check if the text matches, and then set the interior color as the same, but i couldn't make it work without error. And you are correct... the cells in the bottom table will have the same interior colour as the cells in the top table, so it matches the times in both tables :)

Comment: Did you test my answer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next way. I tested the code on two tables existing in the same sheet. You should set them exactly as you need (in separate sheets, the code will also work):

```
Sub matchTableColors()
  Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject, i As Long, dbRng As Range, mtchCell As Range
  
  Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ColoredTableName") 'the one having colored cells
  Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ToBeColoredTbl")   'the one to be colored
  
  Set dbRng = tbl2.DataBodyRange
  'Debug.Print dbRng.address, tbl1.DataBodyRange.address: Stop
  For i = 1 To dbRng.rows.count
        Set mtchCell = tbl1.DataBodyRange.Find(What:=dbRng.cells(i, 1).Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not mtchCell Is Nothing Then
             dbRng.cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = mtchCell.Interior.Color
        End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Note: The column width in the second table **must be fit** or larger than necessary to see all text. I mean `dbRng.cells(i, 1).Text` returns the visible text....

**Edited**:

Please, use the next code to process two ranges (instead of tables)

```
Sub matchNamedRngColors()
  Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, mtchCell As Range
  
  Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("Name1")
  Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("Name2")
  
  For i = 1 To rng2.rows.count
        Set mtchCell = rng1.Find(What:=rng2.cells(i, 1).Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not mtchCell Is Nothing Then
             rng2.cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = mtchCell.Interior.Color
        End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it

Comment: Had a try with your code and edited to fit the current sheet, but it didnt seem to work for me Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject, w As Long, dbRng As Range, mtchCell As Range
  
  Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("times") 'the one having colored cells
  Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("cpttimes")   'the one to be colored
  
  Set dbRng = tbl2.DataBodyRange
  Debug.Print dbRng.Address, tbl1.DataBodyRange.Address: Stop
  For w = 1 To dbRng.Rows.Count
        Set mtchCell = tbl1.DataBodyRange.Find(What:=dbRng.Cells(w, 1).Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

Comment: @Mike T When code stops on `Debug.Print` code line, does it correctly return in `Immediate Window` the two tables `DataBodyRange` addresses? It is there only to check this aspect. Anyhow, I supposed that you know after code stopping on that line **you must press `F5` to make the code continuing**... Now, I commented the code line in discussion anyhow.

Comment: It doesn't no... My vba runs and highlights the ': Stop' in yellow :) but i don't get any error messages

Comment: Is it possible to use my named ranges in both of the table ranges instead? "cpttimes" >the one to be colored and ........"times" > the one having colored cells

Comment: @Mike T Stopping on that line **is not an error**! `Stop` is a debugging break on that line, like I tried suggesting in my above comment. **Did you press `F5` after stopping on the respective line**? And, **please use the code EXACTLY as it is**! why canging `i` with `w`, for instance? You can do whatever you want, but **after seeing it working**...

Comment: Ah, because i already have i set as an integer earlier in my coding, which is storing an important number i need for use after i've sold this little issue :D pressing F5 doesn't really do much :)

Comment: @Mike T Why do not use the code **exactly as it is**? Only the code itself, without caring about an `i` used somewhere else? Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? I would like to connect to your computer if possible. Otherwise, I cannot understand what's happening on your workbook. I tested it on mine and it worked as it should.

Comment: @Mike T Do you understand what you say? How a range to have a `DataBodyRange` property? That's why I insisted to post the code you tried! Why didn't you say anything about that and tried your pseudo adaptation? Why did not answer my question about TeamViewer or AnyDesk? Do you really need help or only wasting our time until we guess what is it about? Do you think we do not have anything to do and are bored, waiting for somebody to give us something to work? You may make a mistake confusing a range with a table but when you could see the answer you should immediately react...

Comment: I tried to just pop it straight into my current project as is and adjust accordingly. I'm having trouble.... just a quick point though, the tables i'm referring too aren't actually tables defined in excel, so thay currently don't have a name! But they are set named ranges though :) can't get teamviewer unfortunately as I'm on a works laptop :D your code works perfectly on two tables in a blank spreadsheet though :) could we edit the original code to used 2 named ranges instead of tables i wonder?

Comment: Calm your passion and cool those jets lad.... tis only a bit of code haha... Yeah i do need help on this final thing to finish my project off, but if you think I'm wasting your time then feel free to move along. Code was excellent tho! Never really used DataBodyRange before.... my coding skills aren't as strong as most

Comment: @Mike T  What I tried emphasizing was the fact that I posted my answer **two hours before** answering the question as it has been formulated. Then we spent that two hours time to clarify something which should be cristal clear from the beginning, or **immediately you observed that you made a mistake, confusing ranges with tables**. In the meantime I also helped some other people, but coming back here to understand why a working code does  not work on your computer... What did I learn from this case?

Comment: @Mike T Please, test the code I posted after **Edited** and send some feedback.

Comment: Ayyyyy we got there in the end me dear :) thanks for the help. With a little tinkering your code slid in like a proper beast. You're a legend, albeit a fiesty one! If you learnt anything from this case, then it should be that your coding knowledge is above and beyond and you should be proud and never shy of your mad skills! Now then.... theres a world to be saved! You know what to do.......... Mike Out ;)